# How to profile thread lifecycle performance

Tags: java, multithreading, webserver, threadpool, profiler

In the context of building an HTTP web server...we understand that theoretically, creating and destroying threads per request is relatively costly and doesn't scale as well. This is common knowledge (or I hope it is). Thread pools are the solution here...but I kind of want to understand things at a lower level than to simply accept the theory as true.

Sure, we can run black-box tests using JMeter to see how an application might perform under load, but what if I want to actually **observe** why it happens? Can a profiler tool tell me how and exactly why thread allocation per request is costly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to measure this yourself you can do this.

When this wisdom was divined is likely to be a long time ago when thread creation was much more expensive. e.g. on Linux, each thread was a new process.

Also "expensive" means different things to different applications.  If every request one your system takes a long time, adding a milli-second won't make much difference.  If every request takes a few milliseconds, adding a milli-second just to start the thread is pretty bad.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ThreadRestarterMain {
    public static void main(String... ignored) throws InterruptedException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // time how long it takes to start a few threads and stop them again.
        int threads = 2000;
        List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (threadList.size() < threads) {
            Thread e = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Thread.yield();
                }
            });
            e.start();
            threadList.add(e);
        }
        for (Thread thread : threadList) {
            thread.join();
        }
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f ms on average to start/stop a thread%n", (double) time / threads);
    }
}
```

This prints something like

```
Took 0.055 ms on average to start/stop a thread
```

Only you know if this is a large number.

Note: If you have thread local resources, this can make this timing much longer.  Again this depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The web server pools threads, which means that a later request may be using the exact same thread, this can be observed by getting a thread ID via Thread.currentThread().getId(). There should not be much to worry about, but if you are planning on creating your own threads from a servlet or filter, don't. This could possibly allow for DOS attack and server flooding. You should be capable of adding monitoring capabilities via a servlet filter which will allow you to pull stats on the current thread as well as do some basic performance stats.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar task a while ago. We decided to stick to JMeter but also added logging to our code. We simply logged the time it took to process specific parts of our code where we suspected bottle necks. Then we ran JMeter to put our system under load.

This way you can't observe all your code but at least different parts of it.

I don't think that this solution is pretty but you might have an idea how to improve it.